# Creating a Linked List of Odd Numbers (C)

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I'm fairly new to coding and am taking a course at school that teaches the C programming language. We are learning about data structures in C and have been given an assignment which requires us to create a linked list with the odd integers from 1 to 10, and also print that list. However, the code that I have written seems to be having some problems. Here it is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct listNode {
    int value;
    struct listNode *nextPtr;
};

typedef struct listNode ListNode;
typedef ListNode *ListNodePtr;

void createList(ListNodePtr *sPtr);
void printList(ListNodePtr currentPtr);

int main(void) {
    ListNodePtr list1Ptr;

    list1Ptr = NULL;

    list1Ptr->value = 1;
    createList(&list1Ptr);
    printf("List 1 is: ");
    printList(list1Ptr);

    printf("End of run.\n");

    return 0;
}

void createList(ListNodePtr *sPtr) {
    ListNodePtr previousPtr;
    ListNodePtr newPtr;

    newPtr = malloc(sizeof(ListNodePtr));

    if (newPtr != NULL) {
        newPtr = *sPtr;

        previousPtr = NULL;

        while (((*sPtr)->value) <= 10) {
            previousPtr = *sPtr;
            *sPtr = (*sPtr)->nextPtr;
            (*sPtr)->value = previousPtr->value + 2;
        }
    } 
    else {
        printf("No memory available.\n");
    }
}

int isEmpty(ListNodePtr sPtr) {
    return sPtr == NULL; 
}

void printList(ListNodePtr currentPtr) {
    if (currentPtr == NULL) {
        printf("List is empty.\n\n");
    }
    else {
        while (currentPtr != NULL) {
            printf("%d ", currentPtr->value);
            currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
        }
        printf("*\n");
    }
}
```

The desired output it: [List 1 is: 1 3 5 7 9 *]
The environment I use keeps telling me that there are either "unhandled exceptions" (I'm not so sure what that means) or just ceases running midway. Any ideas of how I might be able to reach the desired outcome?

Any other tips and words of advice are greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: first problem is: list1Ptr = NULL;

    list1Ptr->value = 1;  you are trying to assign to memory that's not allocated. Step through your code in a  debugger...

Comment: pointers only save address, therefore you need to allocate memory first and de-allocate memory. see malloc and free functions in C

Comment: Off-topic, I'm going to tell you something contrary to what your instructor likely did: *Don't hide pointer types in typedefs*. There are a very small, finite number of cases where it makes actual sense to do so (a blackbox handle-based API, and callback function pointer types are the two that spring to mind). For pretty-much all other cases, it makes the code *harder* to read and excessively prone to `sizeof` mishaps. C programmers *want* to see those asterisks. They're like a billboard announcing to the reader: "This is a pointer." So break that habit, regardless of what your profs says.

Comment: You can even avoid the pointer-to-pointer argument passing, by using the *return* value to *return* the (beginning of the) list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few errors in logic as well as use of `pointers`. May be following code be useful. Comment if any clarification is required:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #define START_COUNT 1
 #define INCREMENT_COUNT 2
 #define END_COUNT 10


 struct listNode {
     int value;
     struct listNode *nextPtr;
 };

 typedef struct listNode ListNode;
 typedef ListNode* ListNodePtr;

 ListNodePtr createList(ListNodePtr sPtr, int val);
 void printList(ListNodePtr currentPtr);

 int main(void) {
     ListNodePtr list1Ptr;
     int counter = END_COUNT;

     list1Ptr = NULL;
     do
     {
         list1Ptr = createList(list1Ptr, START_COUNT);
         counter -= INCREMENT_COUNT;
     }while(counter>0);
     printf("List 1 is: ");
     printList(list1Ptr);

     printf("End of run.\n");

     return 0;
 }

 ListNodePtr createList(ListNodePtr sPtr, int val) {
     ListNodePtr previousPtr;
     ListNodePtr newPtr;
     newPtr = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));

     if (newPtr != NULL) {

         //Make 'newPtr' very first node
         newPtr->nextPtr =sPtr;
         newPtr->value = val;

         sPtr = newPtr;
         //(sPtr != NULL) is to check for [1] and (sPtr->nextPtr != NULL) for [2]
         while ((sPtr != NULL) && (sPtr->nextPtr != NULL) && (sPtr->value <= END_COUNT)) {
             previousPtr = sPtr; //[1]
             sPtr = sPtr->nextPtr; //[2]
             sPtr->value = previousPtr->value + INCREMENT_COUNT; //[1] and [2]
         }
     }
     else {
         printf("No memory available.\n");
     }

     //Set to the very first Node
     return newPtr;
 }

 int isEmpty(ListNodePtr sPtr) {
     return sPtr == NULL;
 }

 void printList(ListNodePtr currentPtr) {
     if (currentPtr == NULL) {
         printf("List is empty.\n\n");
     }
     else {
         while (currentPtr != NULL) {
             printf("%d ", currentPtr->value);
             currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
         }
         printf("*\n");
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (((*sPtr)->value) <= 10) {  <<<<<
    previousPtr = *sPtr;
    *sPtr = (*sPtr)->nextPtr;
    (*sPtr)->value = previousPtr->value + 2;  <<<<<
}
```

You must check `(*sPtr)` for `NULL`, before trying dereferencing it.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the most intuitive interface for such a *constructor* function is

- use the function arguments to supply the parameters to the constructor
- use the return value to pass the produced item(s) to the caller

---

```
struct listNode *listNode_generate(int start, int stop, int step)
{
struct listNode *result, **pp;

if (!step) return NULL;

result = NULL, pp = &result;

for (   ; start <= stop; start += step) {
        *pp = malloc (sizeof **pp);
        if (!*pp) break;
        (*pp)->value = start;
        pp = &(*pp)->next;
        }
*pp = NULL;
return result;
}
```

---

To be called in `main()` like:

---

```
list1Ptr = listNode_generate(1,10,2);
```